# Is it possible to get  Global Exception root cause using struts or JSTL tags?

Tags: struts2

I have configured global Exception mapping for java.lang.Exception and defined tiles results type.

```
<global-exception-mappings>
   <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Is there any way to get the Exception message using strut2 tags or any other jsp OR JSTL tags to find this exception message.

Comment: what do you mean by exception message?

Comment: Root cause of the Exception.  Like in logging mechanism we can write the exception message (Exception.getMessage), similar to that.

Comment: @Arun:Do you want to show some kind of generic exception page to the user or you want to show the exception to the end user

Comment: @Umesh: I need to show the exception to end user for debugging purpose.

Comment: @Arun:See my answer for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display information about the exception in the browser if you want by using s:property tags with a value of exception and exceptionStack. Something like

```
<h4>Exception Name: <s:property value="exception" /> </h4>
<h4>Exception Details: <s:property value="exceptionStack" /></h4>
```

When the exception interceptor is triggered it adds to the fields available for display the exception message and the exception's stack trace and its accessible to the S2tag using normal tag syntax.

For more information read the official S2 document page about Exception Handling

[Exception-Handling](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/exception-handling.html)

Comment: Thank you Umesh, Now I can able to get the exception name and message in the Page.

Comment: @Umesh:  Is it possible to log this exception into log file, I already  configured Log4j for my application with DailyRollAppender.

Comment: @Arun: yes its quite possible, just follow the link i have provided in my answer with section **Logging Exceptions**

Comment: @Umesh: I tried logging mechanism similar to that, but it is not working. My Code Snippet is 

<interceptors>
<interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="SessionInterceptor" />
 <interceptor-stack name="myInterceptorStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
  <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
       <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
 </interceptor-ref>
 <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

Answer (score 1):

Define the property tag in global result page.

```
<s:property value="exception"/> 
<s:property value="exceptionStack"/>
```